# How to watch a for-loop in bash?

Tags: bash, for, watch

Is it possible to use a `for`-loop with the `watch` command?

I'm not really sure what to make of this error with what I've tried:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
$ watch -n 10 for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
$ watch for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`watch`'s *command* argument(s) are a script that is run with `sh -c`.

If the *command* arguments are just a list of tokens separated by spaces (e.g. `watch ls -l`), it concatenates them all and runs them.   But unquoted shell meta-characters are **used by the shell that you run `watch` from** and are **never seen by `watch`**.

This means that meta-characters like `;` `&` `|` `<` `>` etc need to be escaped or quoted to prevent the shell in which you run `watch` from seeing those characters as, e.g., instructions to mark the end the `watch` command, run the watch command in the background, or pipe the output of `watch` into another program (rather than run the pipe inside the watch script).

The usual quoting rules apply - single-quotes to prevent variable interpolation, double-quotes otherwise.  `man watch` has an EXAMPLES section at the end showing this.

For example:

```
watch -n 10 'for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done'
```

or

```
watch -n 10 'grep something /var/log/kern.log | tail'
```

Note: you can use `watch`'s `-x` option if you want to exec something without `sh -c`.  e.g. `watch -x awk -f script.awk`.

Answer (score 1):

The command you typed was parsed by your current shell before the shell even attempted to run `watch`. The shell interpreted `;` and `do` because you did nothing to protect these from the shell. `do` was unexpected, but in the first place you did not want the shell to interpret `;` as a command terminator.

In general you protect things from being interpreted/expanded by the shell with escaping (e.g. `\;`) or quoting (e.g. `';'`). In your case you need to protect `;` and `$`. But then there's a question: what will `watch` do?

Normally `watch` does not just run a command. It runs shell code, i.e. passes some code to `sh -c`. The code is crafted from one or more arguments to `watch` (so e.g. `watch echo foo` works like `watch "echo foo"`).

There is `watch -x` which runs a command without a shell, but to run a `for` loop you do need a shell.

The fact `watch` can build shell code from multiple arguments can lead to bugs when multiple spaces matter and you're not careful with quoting. Another command that does something similar is `ssh` and you can find some analysis in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690).

A way to deal with all these problems is to single-quote *everything* you want to be the shell code, so `watch` gets *exactly one* argument containing the code. In your case:

```
watch -n 10 'for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done'
```

Note in general the code `watch` will run in `sh` needs its own quoting and sometimes one needs single-quotes *there*, so simply embracing the entire code with new single-quotes may or may not work. It will not work (or in the best case it will work by chance) if the new single-quotes pair with already existing single-quotes, not with each other, in the context of the current shell. Please see [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690). The linked question contains a universal manual solution; my answer there provides a way to automate such quoting in Bash.